# Mathematical formula for Math.clz32

Tags: javascript, python, math

I was trying to implement the Javascript-method [Math.clz32](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/clz32) in Python. The method I've been able to come up with is:

```py
def clz32(x):
     x = x % 2 ** 32
     if x == 0: return 32
     return 34 - len(bin(x))
```

This method works, but I've been wondering whether there is a pure mathematical formula for this.

Comment: This implementation is incorrect. `Math.clz32(4294967299)` is 30, not 32.

Comment: Out of interest, what are you using this for? Python integers are unbounded rather than fixed-width, so something like `clz32` isn't a particularly natural operation. It may make more sense to raise `ValueError` for values outside the range `[0, 2**32)`. (Unless you need absolute compatibility with JavaScript, for some reason?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bit_length` method, which returns the number of bits required to represent the integer.  Since we are only interested in the leading zero bits, we will subtract this number from 32.  Note that this does not account for negative numbers, so `clz32(-1)` will return 0.

```py
def clz32(x):
    if x < 0:
        return 0
    return 32 - x.bit_length()
```

Comment: I cannot find a `math.clz32` in python 3.8. Do you have a reference?